# Getting size of a symbol

Tags: c, linux-kernel

I'm trying to get a size of an existing symbol in kernel space (checked through `/proc/kallsyms`), which does not belong to any module.

Mainly I looked into `include/linux/kallsyms.h` and `kernel/kallsyms.c` and the only exported function, which partially gives me what I want, is `sprint_symbol`, which prints symbol parameters into a buffer.

Parsing a buffer to get a symbol size does not seem to me to be a good solution, but I really can't figure out how could I do this differently (I even tried "cheating" kernel with using `kallsyms_lookup_name` for functions like `lookup_symbol_attrs` or `kallsyms_lookup`, but they couldn't be resolved).

Is there any other way, that I've missed?

Comment: Can you explain a bit better what are you trying to achieve? What do you mean the size of an existing symbol? You know symbols are name that identify an memory area?

Comment: Yes. I want to achieve the same thing, that for e.g. `lookup_name_attrs` returns in `size` parameter, but I can't use this functions, because it's not exported.

Comment: And when it comes to symbols, that belong to a module, you can get to their size through `symtab` in `module` structure.

Comment: You can subtract the address of the next symbol from the current symbol, as you can see in System.map, you can subtract two preceding address and get roughly the first symbol size. I hope I did understand your question properly

Comment: Yeah, I saw that in implementation of kallsyms static functions, but problem is when symbol is the last one in section and I couldn't manage to compile my code, because these sections were undefined (meaning macros that define these sections). I guess it's another problem, when creating code in module.